# KivyMD trying to add instances of a widget (progressbar) to a Screen

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

**.py file**

```
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass 

class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class MyWorkouts(Screen):
    pass

class RecommendedWorkouts(Screen):
    pass

class AddWorkouts(Screen):
    pass

class CreateNewWorkout(Screen):
    pass

class AddNewGoal(Screen):
    pass


class Workout(MDApp):
    dialog = None

def build(self):
    return

def AddNewGoal_Dialog(self):
    if not self.dialog:
        self.dialog = MDDialog(
            size_hint_x = 0.8,
            size_hint_y = 1,
            pos_hint = {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5},
            radius = [10, 10, 10, 10],
            title = 'Add New Goal',
            auto_dismiss = False,
            type = 'custom',
            content_cls = AddNewGoal(),
            buttons = [
                MDFlatButton(
                    text = 'CANCEL', text_color = self.theme_cls.primary_color, 
                    on_release = self.closeDialog),
                MDRaisedButton(
                    text = 'CREATE', text_color = self.theme_cls.primary_color,
                    on_release = self.addNewGoal)
                    
                ],
        )
    self.dialog.open()

def addNewGoal(self, inst):
    progressbar = ProgressBar()
    HomeScreen().add_widget(progressbar)
```

**.kv file**

```
MDToolbar:
    title: 'App Attack'
    type: 'top'
    right_action_items: [['plus', lambda x: app.AddNewGoal_Dialog()]]
    elevation: 10
```

So, when I press the right action item on the toolbar, it creates the Dialog. Then, I want it so when I press the CREATE Raised Button on the Dialog, it will then add a widget (a progressbar) to the Home Screen. I don't get an **error code**. Instead, when the button is released, nothing happens. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line in your `addNewGoal()` method:

```
HomeScreen().add_widget(progressbar)
```

creates a new instance of `HomeScreen`, and adds the `progressbar` to that instance. Unfortunately, that instance of `HomeScreen` is not the one that is in your GUI. You need to get a reference to the instance of `HomeScreen` that is in your GUI. If your posted `kv` file is accurate, then there is no instance of `HomeScreen`. However, I suspect you have not provided your complete `kv` file.

If your `addNewGoal()` method is a method of your `App` (also not clear from your posted code), then that line in `addNewGoal()` should be something like:

```
self.root.get_screen('homescreen').add_widget(progressbar)
```

That assume that the root of your GUI is a `ScreenManager` and that the `name` of your `HomeScreen` is `homescreen`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was stuck on that for too long! Great explanation as well.